# ios/mac - Android Studio: Flutter SDK path doesnt set

Tags: android-studio, flutter

**Steps to Reproduce:**
 1. Open Android Studio IDE on Mac (Flutter plugin already installed)
 2. *Android Studio* > *Preferences..* > *Language & Frameworks* > *Flutter*
 3. Section SDK: Set Flutter SDK path
 4: Press *Apply*

**Expected:**
Path should be set and remain in the text box

**Actual:**
Path disappears from Flutter SDK path text box, no path is set and cant go on programming

As I work on a group project, i regulary have to pull from github. After every pull, i had to reset the Flutter SDK path (dont really know why but it kept disappearing). It used to work just fine until some days ago, the behavior explained on top started. Any help would be really appreciated!

**Video:** http://sendvid.com/vlt9ykpz

Comment: Have you set up PATH variable with flutter bin repository?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yeah i have. I'm not new to flutter and I've worked on this project for months now. The setting of the Flutter SDK Path just suddenly stopped working as shown in the video

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone else has the same problem: Deleting the local copy and pulling the whole project from git again fixed the issue in my case. Just dont forget to copy your local changes as the would be deleted aswell

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this while moving the location of the Flutter SDK.

After all the files were in place, restarting the IDE showed the correct path after it had been disappearing before restart.

`C:\dev\tools\flutter_sdk\flutter` (folder that contains `flutter\bin`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't commit the `android/local.properties` file (add it to `.gitignore`)
or update the path using `flutter config --android-sdk path` after checkout.

Comment: That helped for futher pushes and pulls, in my case i just deleted the whole project and pulled it again from git, setting the flutter path worked afterwards. Thanks anway!

Answer (score 0):

having the same issue on ubuntu 20, installed flutter with snapd