# Flutter - Android Studio - Why is "Flutter attach" and "Hot reload" buttons greyed out on Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, hot-reload, flutter-hotreload

I have an existing **native Android app** to which I am adding a **Flutter module** (as new screens of the app will be written in Flutter).

This is my project structure:

```
native_project
   app
   flutter_module
   network_module
   .
   .
   .
```

I can get hot reload to work by opening the terminal and manually navigating to `native_project/flutter_module` and then running `flutter attach`. After that, changes to the Flutter files can be hot reloaded *from the terminal* by typing "r".

I don't want to use the terminal for hot reloading though. Instead, I want to be able to use the "hot reload" button in Android Studio but no matter what I do, it is always grayed out:

[image]

You can see both the "Flutter Hot Reload" button (the lighting icon) and the "Flutter attach" button (the device icon with the Flutter icon on it) are greyed out (they are greyed out even when hot reloading is working from the terminal).

How can I get those buttons to work on Android Studio?

Here is my Android Studio configuration for Flutter SDK and Dart SDK:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you added flutter sdk path in project setting?
if not goto
file -> settings -> languages and frameworks -> flutter ->
then select flutter SDK from the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Kind of. I can select my flutter SDK folder (and it seems to recognise it because it shows the Flutter version and channel below the field just like your screenshot) but as soon as I click on Apply or OK the field becomes empty again. I can't seem to have it persist. My Flutter SDK is under ~/Documents/flutter

Comment: This is the problem I am having when trying to set the Flutter SDK in Android Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52630818/1369016

Comment: I've fixed the SDK path issue above but the original issue remains.

Comment: can you please post a a screenshot of your android studio?

Comment: I've added screenshots.

Comment: Bro I mean the screenshot of your ide screen including the hot reload and restart buttons and device configuration not the settings.